# How to use phone number as username for Django authentication

Tags: django

I'm trying to expand the user model and use the username phone number instead.I'm create a custom User model and a custom Manager for the new User model.

**models.py**

```
from django.contrib.auth.models import AbstractUser, BaseUserManager
from django.core.validators import RegexValidator
from django.db import models
from django.utils.translation import ugettext_lazy as _


class UserManager(BaseUserManager):
    """Define a model manager for User model with no username field."""

    use_in_migrations = True

    def _create_user(self, phone, password, **extra_fields):
        """Create and save a User with the given phone and password."""
        if not phone:
            raise ValueError('The given phone must be set')
        self.phone = phone
        user = self.model(phone=phone, **extra_fields)
        user.set_password(password)
        user.save(using=self._db)
        return user

    def create_user(self, phone, password=None, **extra_fields):
        """Create and save a regular User with the given phone and password."""
        extra_fields.setdefault('is_staff', False)
        extra_fields.setdefault('is_superuser', False)
        return self._create_user(phone, password, **extra_fields)

    def create_superuser(self, phone, password, **extra_fields):
        """Create and save a SuperUser with the given phone and password."""
        extra_fields.setdefault('is_staff', True)
        extra_fields.setdefault('is_superuser', True)

        if extra_fields.get('is_staff') is not True:
            raise ValueError('Superuser must have is_staff=True.')
        if extra_fields.get('is_superuser') is not True:
            raise ValueError('Superuser must have is_superuser=True.')

        return self._create_user(phone, password, **extra_fields)

class User(AbstractUser):
    """User model."""

    username = None
    email = models.EmailField(blank=True, null=True)
    phone_regex = RegexValidator(regex=r'^\+?1?\d{9,15}$', message="Phone number must be entered in the format: '+999999999'. Up to 15 digits allowed.")
    phone = models.CharField(_('phone number'), validators=[phone_regex], max_length=17, unique=True) # validators should be a list
    is_partner = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    is_client = models.BooleanField(default=False)


    USERNAME_FIELD = 'phone'
    REQUIRED_FIELDS = ['email']
    
    objects = UserManager()
```

I'm done makemigrations and migrate, all it's Ok! But then I try create superuser, after adding fields (phone, email, password) an error is occured:

```
NameError: name 'phone' is not defined
```

Comment: in your `_create_user` method why are you using `phone=self.phone`? I think that's triggering the error: try deleting that line

Comment: I did not understand why, but it works

Comment: Yeah that's the beauty of our world hehe. I think it's because UserManager doesn't have `phone` attribute. Also `phone=self.phone` is not good, if you are receiving a param (phone) is to set the model attribute `self.phone=phone` not the other way around.

Answer (score 1):

You pass email and passwort to create_superuser(), maybe you want to pass phone instead?

Comment: Yes, my inattention. I fixed it. But new mistake is occured `phone = self.phone
AttributeError: 'UserManager' object has no attribute 'phone'`

Comment: You can only use phone= self.phone if you already assigned phone to self. (Self.phone = my_phone_number).

Answer (score 1):

Did you register your custom user model in `settings.py` by mentioning `AUTH_USER_MODEL = 'myapp.MyUser'`? Unless this is done, your model will not be treated as user model.